# how do i get a value from a dictionnary format ('B','A'):value

Tags: python

i generated a dictionnary out of a table and it looks a bit like that :

```
d= {'D', 'V'): -5, ('N', 'M'): -3, ('X', 'M'): -1, ('W', 'S'): -4, 
    ('R', 'C'): -5, ('X', 'Z'): -1, ('V', 'W'): -3, ('B', 'J'): -5, 
    ('R', 'N'): -1, ('M', 'T'): -1, ('S', 'I'): -3, ('X', 'B'): -1, 
    ('R', 'L'): -3, ('S', 'C'): -2, ('H', 'M'): -3, ('I', 'X'): -1, 
    ('W', 'H'): -3, ('Q', 'H'): 1, ('K', '*'): -6, ('E', 'I'): -4, 
    ('R', 'P'): -3, ('F', 'S'): -3, ('C', 'M'): -2, ('X', 'V'): -1, 
    ('S', 'S'): 5, ('V', 'I'): 3, ('S', 'X'): -1, ('E', 'M'): -3, 
    ('M', 'F'): -1, ('R', 'S'): -1, ('Y', 'N'): -3}
```

two strings `s1="SACV" and s2="XSCS"` 
i want to get the value for `('S','X')`
how do i get the value doing `d[[s1[S]][s2[X]]]` i get

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

and doing `d[[s1[S]]+[s2[X]]]` i get

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Welcome! You should format your post. Actually it is not very readable...

Comment: new in the forum  sorry is it clear now ?

Comment: It's not clear whether `('S', 'X')` comes from the first character of each of `s1` and `s2`, as the other pairs don't correspond to keys. I don't see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to correct this:

`d= {'D', 'V'): -5, (...)` >> `d= {('D', 'V'): -5, (...)`

after doing it you just need to call it as:
`return d[('S', 'X')]` or `print d[('S', 'X')]`

This should work. Otherwise just let us know

Comment: This worked for me:d= {('D', 'V'): -5, ('N', 'M'): -3, ('X', 'M'): -1, ('W', 'S'): -4,
    ('R', 'C'): -5, ('X', 'Z'): -1, ('V', 'W'): -3, ('B', 'J'): -5,
    ('R', 'N'): -1, ('M', 'T'): -1, ('S', 'I'): -3, ('X', 'B'): -1,
    ('R', 'L'): -3, ('S', 'C'): -2, ('H', 'M'): -3, ('I', 'X'): -1,
    ('W', 'H'): -3, ('Q', 'H'): 1, ('K', '*'): -6, ('E', 'I'): -4,
    ('R', 'P'): -3, ('F', 'S'): -3, ('C', 'M'): -2, ('X', 'V'): -1,
    ('S', 'S'): 5, ('V', 'I'): 3, ('S', 'X'): -1, ('E', 'M'): -3,
    ('M', 'F'): -1, ('R', 'S'): -1, ('Y', 'N'): -3}

print d[('S','X')]